# .Net Core 3.5 Blazor optional int route parameters

Tags: .net-core, parameters, routes, blazor, blazor-server-side

Trying to figure out how to make my int route parameters optional without resorting to processing a querystring.  For example, if I wanted param1 and param2 to be optional.  If I try leaving int parameters blank when passing it in, it won't match the route at all.  So

```
https://localhost/MyComponent///testString
```

doesn't work with the code as it is below.  I realize I could just pass in 0, but this is a curiosity for me at this point :).

```
@page "/MyComponent/{param1:int}/{param2:int}/{param3}"

@code {
    [Parameter] public int? Param1 { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public int? Param2 { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string Param3 { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use multiple `@page` attributes

`MyComponent.razor`

```
@page "/MyComponent"
@page "/MyComponent/{param3}"
@page "/MyComponent/{param1:int}/{param2:int}/{param3}"
@page "/MyComponent/{param1:int}/null/{param3}"
@page "/MyComponent/null/{param2:int}/{param3}"
@page "/MyComponent/null/null/{param3}"

<div class="d-flex flex-column">
<div>Param1 @Param1</div>
<div>Param2 @Param2</div>
<div>Param3 @Param3</div>

<a href="/MyComponent/Test 1">Test 1</a>
<a href="/MyComponent/1/2/Test 2">Test 2</a>
<a href="/MyComponent/3/null/Test 3">Test 3</a>
<a href="/MyComponent/null/4/Test 4">Test 4</a>
<a href="/MyComponent/null/null/Test 5">Test 5</a>
</div>
@code {
    [Parameter] public int? Param1 { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public int? Param2 { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string Param3 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Not ideal, but I'm stuck not being able to upgrade to .net 5 just yet, so this works :) I just have to be sure to keep my routes manageable this way, can easily get out of hand.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For enet.  I copied this from my VS window:

```
@page "/counter/{currentCount:int?}/{Param1:int?}"

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p>Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
    // private int currentCount = 0;

    [Parameter] public int currentCount { get; set; } = 0;
    [Parameter] public int Param1 { get; set; }


    private void IncrementCount() {
        currentCount++;
    }

    protected override void OnInitialized() {
        currentCount = currentCount + Param1;


        base.OnInitialized();
    }
}
```

Comment: No way... It must work. It works on my devise. Tell you what, double click on the name of your project (not solution). You should see something like this: <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
If you have something else, remove and save it somewhere

Comment: Hmmmm... <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>

Comment: Why don't you upgrade to .Net 5.0 ? Anyhow, it should work in all the versions of Blazor. If you are interested, upload your complete project to github, or post here a zipped link and I'll run it on my devise. The code should work........

Comment: Not possible at the moment since it's for work.  It doesn't work in this version of Blazor, obviously.  At least maybe I can look forward to it working in .Net 5 when we get around to upgrading.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's for work". Man, you should have created a newly brand app, .Net 5.0, go to the default template for the Counter component, and replace its content with my code.

Comment: I mean this issue is coming up at my job, so I can't just upgrade to .Net 5 willy-nilly.  I don't doubt that it would work if I had a .Net 5 project though.